# How to click on the angularjs enabled element with ng-click

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have below page and I need to click on User Login.

I am unable to locate an element to proceed with.

```
<a class="nav-link page-scroll login-a ng-binding" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginToast" href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="vm.showLoginToast({},'login');" ng-class="{'urdu-login-mobile':language==='UR' || language==='ur'}">User Login</a>
```

Comment: Kindly donot post images of your code instead copy paste them so that we can debug it easily.

Comment: <a class="nav-link page-scroll login-a ng-binding" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginToast" href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="vm.showLoginToast({},'login');" ng-class="{'urdu-login-mobile':language==='UR' || language==='ur'}">User Login</a>

Comment: Can you explain your question a bit more it is not clear what is the error , what is the expected output.

Comment: unique identifier as in id attribute?

Comment: yes, as in id attribute

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32499174/selenium-click-event-does-not-trigger-angularjs-ng-click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element is [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so to `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element to be clickable` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *Java* and *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a.nav-link.page-scroll.login-a.ng-binding[data-toggle='modal'][data-target$='loginToast']"))).click();
  ```
- Using *Python* and *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='nav-link page-scroll login-a ng-binding' and @data-toggle='modal'][text()='User Login']"))).click()
  ```

Comment: @ShipraSaxena As per StackOverflow best practices you need to raise a new question with your new requirement, Stackoverflow contributors will be happy to help you out and you can choose the best answer among several which caters to your need.